# How to get the indices of the tapped List item in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, macos, swiftui

I have a expandable List in SwiftUI, the List item model is defined as(MenuItem.swift):

```
struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var subMenuItems: [MenuItem]?
}
// Sub-menu items for Espressco Machines
let espressoMachineMenuItems = [ MenuItem(name: "Leva", image: "leva-x", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "Leva X", image: "leva-x"), MenuItem(name: "Leva S", image: "leva-s") ]),
                                 MenuItem(name: "Strada", image: "strada-ep", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "Strada EP", image: "strada-ep"), MenuItem(name: "Strada AV", image: "strada-av"), MenuItem(name: "Strada MP", image: "strada-mp"), MenuItem(name: "Strada EE", image: "strada-ee") ]),
                                 MenuItem(name: "KB90", image: "kb90"),
                                 MenuItem(name: "Linea", image: "linea-pb-x", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "Linea PB X", image: "linea-pb-x"), MenuItem(name: "Linea PB", image: "linea-pb"), MenuItem(name: "Linea Classic", image: "linea-classic") ]),
                                 MenuItem(name: "GB5", image: "gb5"),
                                 MenuItem(name: "Home", image: "gs3", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "GS3", image: "gs3"), MenuItem(name: "Linea Mini", image: "linea-mini") ])
                                ]

// Sub-menu items for Grinder
let grinderMenuItems = [ MenuItem(name: "Swift", image: "swift"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Vulcano", image: "vulcano"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Swift Mini", image: "swift-mini"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Lux D", image: "lux-d")
                        ]

// Sub-menu items for other equipment
let otherMenuItems = [ MenuItem(name: "Espresso AV", image: "espresso-av"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Espresso EP", image: "espresso-ep"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Pour Over", image: "pourover"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Steam", image: "steam")
                        ]
```

In ContentView.swift, I define a expandable List:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Set<UUID> = []
    var body: some View {
        
        List(sampleMenuItems, children: \.subMenuItems) { item in
            // item is of type MenuItem
            HStack {
                if let image=item.image{
                    Image(image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                }

                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                    .bold()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("item selected=\(item.name)")
                        
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The List is 2 or 3 level expandable:

[image: List]

When I tap a List Item, I can get the item name in .onTapGesture, But what I want to get are the indices of the tapped item in sampleMenuItems List(take item "Leva S" for example, it is sampleMenuItems[0].subMenuItems![0].subMenuItems![1])

How can I do this in my code?

Comment: I have to ask why you would need to have those indices? Maybe there’s a better solution

Comment: IMO it should be solved at model layer, by making tree reverse-traversable, ie. use bi-directional tree as model instead.

Comment: Use the `id` property. That is what you need to access.  This will then let you find the right item in your model